# Find height of body content in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If i have a wrapped that includes a header -> body -> footer how do i calculate the height of the body content.

I have set up my wrapper like so:

```
var DefaultWrapper = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <div>
      <Header currentPage={this.props.children.type.displayName} />
      {this.props.children}
      <Footer position={this.state.position} />
    </div>
  }
});
```

I want to calculate the height of whatever component/page gets added to `this.props.children`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until changes are flushed to the DOM. According to the React DOC (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) it would be the lifecycle function `componentDidUpdate: function() {...}`.

*Be aware that for the initial render the `componentDidUpdate: function() {...}` is not called instead the `componentDidMount: function() {...}`*

Inside this function you can access the DOM-Element between your Header and Footer React Component and simply get the height of it (e.g. with jQuery or 'offsetHeight').

Here an example:

```
var DefaultWrapper = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <div>
      <Header currentPage={this.props.children.type.displayName} />
      <div ref='content'>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
      <Footer position={this.state.position} />
    </div>
  },
componentDidUpdate: function() {
  // do whatever you want
  var heightOfContent = this.getContentHeight();
  },
componentDidMount: function() {
  // on your first render componentDidMount is called instead
  // of componentDidUpdate

  var heightOfContent = this.getContentHeight();
  // do whatever you want
  },
getContentHeight: function() {
  // get the DOM element of the content and get its height
  return this.refs.content.offsetHeight
  }
});
```

Off course you can also simply skip the ref and simply add an id attribute and access the DOM-Element with pure JS or jQuery